# My Account dropdown template

Tags: magento-enterprise, template

Does anybody know where I can find the template on the image below?

[image]

I need to add social buttons under login but I don't know where to find the template 
I'm using RWD Theme of Magento Enterprise 1.4

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a template, as such.

The links are created by this line (~ line 98 or so)

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
```

That name is referenced in page.xml (~ line 93)

```
<block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
```

Which leads back to Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links.php.

So, you will need to add any more links via your local.xml - something like:

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title">
<label>About Us</label>
<url>about-us</url>
<title>About Us</title>
<prepare>true</prepare>
<urlParams helper="core/url/getHomeUrl"/>
<position>1</position>
<liParams>id="about-us-li"</liParams>
<aParams>class="top-link" id="about-us-top-link"</aParams>
<beforeText/>
<afterText>|</afterText>
</action>
```

The added links would go inside of a reference to the topLinks block -

```
<block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
<action method="addLink" translate="label title">
...
*link code goes here*
...
</action>
```

There is an explanation / tutorial [here](http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/magento-tutorials/adding-custom-links-local-xml/)

I wish there were better news, but unfortunately I think that is the best way of handling it. Of course, if someone else has a shortcut I am all ears!

You could replace the links template totally and create something of your own with social logos, etc, but that would involve changing the original xml reference as well.

I hope this is helpful. Good luck!

Comment: Hi. I tried it it's not working though. Do you know how to edit the word "Log In" on the dropdown?

Comment: Have you tried handling that in the translate.csv for your locale? Just create a new line with: "Log In", "Your Version of Log In". If that line is translation ready (lots of stock Magento labels are) then it will change to your text immediately. Well, you may have to clear the cache... As far as a bigger menu fix, you could write your own "menuLinks.phtml" or something, then add it to your header via xml, then do a getChildHtml on the template to get it into the header. It's a bit of a pain, but if you want custom links there it may be easier, and you don't have to deal with the stock file.